# Multiple URLs for one page

Tags: docusaurus

Is there a way to have more than one URL for a [page](https://docusaurus.io/docs/create-doc)?

I have:

```
---
slug: /foo
---
```

I want the page to load with `/foo` or `/bar`.

I suppose I could make another file with the other slug and have it mimic content... but hoping there is another way.

Comment: hi, yes this might be of interest https://docusaurus.io/docs/next/api/plugins/@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs#slug (or https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/plugins/@docusaurus/plugin-client-redirects)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Wondering the same thing

Comment: ‍♂️ yeah, sign me in. This is quite useful tbh.